# python shift decimal point in a String number

Tags: python

Is there a easy way to shift a decimal point in a string?  e.g. "1032" becomes "10.32" and "235.2" becomes "2.352".

Comment: Convert it to a `float`, divide it by `10 ** n` (including negative values of `n`),  and then format it back into a string (using the desired decimal places)?

Comment: I heard float has some rounding errors don't know if thats going to be a problem

Comment: Yes, floating-point is inexact (though you can use [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) if you know the precision you care about).

Comment: Voting to reopen since I don't see how this is too broad or vague or anything. There's a clearly defined task here. Although, I feel like it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) and divide by 100:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal as D
>>> for s in '1032', '235.2':
...     print(D(s) / 100)
...
10.32
2.352
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> for s in '1032', '235.2':
...     print(re.sub(r'(..)(\.|$)', r'.\1', s))
... 
10.32
2.352
```

Comment: It fails for `s="1"`

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> x = "1234.56789"
>>> left_shift = 2
>>> split = x.split(".")
>>> "".join([split[0][:-left_shift], ".", split[0][-left_shift:], split[1]])
'12.3456789'
```

But be careful when the decimal point is absent or within `left_shift` characters of the beginning of the string!

Comment: This fails on `x = "1032"` which is one of the examples in the question.